# Как возвратить массив в методе в Java

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Здравствуйте, сильно не пинайте, но не могу понять как я могу вставить массив в `return` метода.

В `return` *questions* красного цвета.

Есть ли какая нибудь возможность, возвратить массив при вызове метода?

```
public class Questions {
    int dataBaseID;
    String question;
    String answer;


    public String[] DBConnect(Context context) {
        // Подключение базы
        MyDatabase mMyDatabase = new MyDatabase(context);
        final SQLiteDatabase database = mMyDatabase.getWritableDatabase();
        //*****
        Cursor cursor = database.query(MyDatabase.DATABASE_TABLE, null, null, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            int idIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(MyDatabase.KEY_ID);
            int questionIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(MyDatabase.KEY_QUESTION);
            int answerIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(MyDatabase.KEY_ANSWER);
            do {

                Questions[] questions = {
                        new Questions(cursor.getInt(idIndex), cursor.getString(questionIndex), cursor.getString(answerIndex)),
                };
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        cursor.close();
        return questions;
    }


    private Questions(int dataBaseID, String question, String answer) {
        this.dataBaseID = dataBaseID;
        this.answer = answer;
        this.question = question;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Проблема не в том, что это массив, а в том, что объявили ссылку не в той области видимости, в которой возвращаете результат. Надо так:

```
Questions[] questions = null;
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        //...
}
cursor.close();
return questions;
```

Comment: А то что в сигнатуре `String[]`, а возвращается `Questions[]`?

Comment: Ну это уже автор у себя ошибся. Я думаю, поправить не вызовет трудностей.

Answer (score 2):

Согласен с ответом от Vladimir Parfenov.

Добавлю только рекомендацию использовать конструкцию:

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(...);
try {
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        ...
    }
} finally {
    cursor.close();
}
```

Или в случае минимального API 19+, Вы можете использовать try-with-resources:

```
try (Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(...)) {
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Не "целевого API 19+", а минимального API 19+ (minSdkVersion=19 или выше).

Comment: @eugene Спасибо, исправил.